# ListView passing OnItemClick position to another class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite

What I want to achieve - is to pass the position of the clicked item in my ListView to another Java class. The position will be an index in my array what refers to a specific query to SQLite's table

Also, I thought to use putExtra or Bundle but because I don't have OnCreate in MyDBClass I don't know where to put the code to retrieve the passing data.

TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity.java

```
package com.example.dissertation;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String array_topics[] = new String[] {"test1",
                                            "test2",
                                            "test3",};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_traffic_signs);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_TopicSigns);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_topics);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity.this, TrafficSignsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

MyDBClass.java

```
  package com.example.dissertation.SQLitePackage;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

    import com.example.dissertation.DataTransmission;
    import com.example.dissertation.RecyclePackage.DBModelClass;
    import com.example.dissertation.TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity;
    import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MyDBClass extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dissertation_database.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        Context context;
         String queries[] = new String[] {"SELECT * FROM test1_table","SELECT * FROM test2_table"};

        public MyDBClass(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;

        }


    public ArrayList<DBModelClass> getData_SignActivity(){

            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ArrayList<DBModelClass> objDBModelClass = new ArrayList<>();
            if(sqLiteDatabase != null){
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queries[index],null);
                if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                            String TextView = cursor.getString(1);
                            byte[] ImageView = cursor.getBlob(2);
                            if (ImageView == null){
                                objDBModelClass.add(
                                        new DBModelClass(
                                                TextView
                                        ));
                            }
                            else{
                                Bitmap ourImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ImageView,0,ImageView.length);
                                objDBModelClass.add(
                                        new DBModelClass(
                                                TextView,ourImage
                                        )
                                );
                            }

                        }

                }
    /*            else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Database is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                }*/

            }return  objDBModelClass;
    /*        else
                {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Database doesn't exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }*/
        }
    }
```

Below is what if have tried so far:

I used getter and setter
In TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity

```
private int;
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
```

and in onItemClick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity.this, TrafficSignsActivity.class);
            setIndex(position); // added
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

After that in MyDbCLASS.java

```
TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity index = new TrafficSignsDashBoardActivity();
int get_index = index.getIndex();
```

and in Cursor rawQuery

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queries[get_index],null);
```

Comment: Pass it by Intent, but change `getData_SignActivity()` to `getData_SignActivity(int index)`, and just get index from Intent inside `Activity` where you call it. If you have to call it without `index`, then pass "-1" and make `if (){} else {}` statement and check if `index < 0`

Comment: You know what, this is a good idea i didn't think about this. I will try right know ! =)

Comment: TO Skype Dogg, Thank you mate. I did what you suggested and it works perfectly!

Comment: That's good, happy coding ;)